# IOS setting up and loading multiple/long test conditions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I am new to programming. I am wondering what is the best way to set up a fairly long test conditions? Instead of writing a lot of if() else() statement, can I putting all the test conditions in a Plist file or a Dictionary so that it is much more manageable?

Thanks
Jeno

Comment: Can you give us an example on what you'd like to test and how you would implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Well let's look at the example

**Example**

plist containing some entries:

```
name(NSString*): Tom
age(int): 15
gender(NSString*): male
```

**Testing **

To test automatically I would put all my properties of an User object into an array.

```
userProperties = [@"Blake", 10, @"male"]

For every entry in userProperties array
  if property at index i is equal to property at index i in plist
     print YES
  else
     print NO
```

Note: you may have to check what type of class is an object so that you choose proper checkup function. Meaning for NSString you would use `[NSString isEqualToString:@"string"]` and for int you would use `==`

In short. It all depends on what you want to do.